# SP site not opening in SP designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, error, version

Server Error: "The version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation running on the server is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer you are using. You need a more recent version of SharePoint Designer"**

I have a test app site collection and production app site collection in SharePoint 2013. The test app site collection `http://abctest.who.gov/apps/` opens in the SharePoint designer 2013 and the prod site collection `http://abc.who.gov/apps/` do not  open in the same designer. Any idea please.

Comment: what about different office versions like in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4d404225-c275-4499-a08e-e05a54a89bb9/server-error-the-version-of-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-running-on-the-server-is-more-recent?forum=sharepointadmin ? ... assuming that your prod-environment is setup separately. Or this strange reassignment the SPD faces sometimes discussed in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-error-the-version-of-microsoft/92ec4ad6-3ffc-40b8-8814-0ef8db4ce7de ?

Comment: ....we also had a similar thread here. Look at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112607/open-sharepoint-online-web-with-sharepoint-designer-gives-server-error-saying-it

Comment: @Celophysis Thanks. Trying to get the same version of the office package.